# For each real number $x$, could there be an integer $N(x)$ such that $N(x) < x < N(x) + 1?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

By Archemdian(?), if $[A] \le A < [A] + 1$ for any $A \in \mathbb R$ where $[A]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $A$. So, the answer is yes. I am not sure if my reasoning is correct. I am also unsure about the answer given in the back of my book:

> $0 < x - N(x) < 1$ which is impossible when $x$ is an integer.

By itself the quoted statement makes sense, but didn't we assume $x$ was real, not an integer? Please, comment on this.

Comment: Some real numbers are integers. $0$ for example. Or $-17$.

Comment: Integer numbers *are* real. So when you assume "$x$ is a real number", you are not disconsidering the possibility of $x$ being, in particular, an integer (unless, of course, explicitly stated).

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer, In other words, the author is saying that the relation must hold for all reals, not just some, right?

Comment: Integers are also real numbers.  So "for each real number $x$"  includes the case, for instance, where $x=1$.   

The statement: "For each real number $x$, could there be an integer $N(x)$ such that $N(x) < x < N(x) + 1$"  is FALSE (just take $x=1$). 

On the other hand, the slightly modified statement: "For each real number $x$, could there be an integer $N(x)$ such that $N(x) \leqslant  x < N(x) + 1$". is true.  In this case, if $x$ is integer, $N(x)=x$.

Comment: Not one $N$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ of course, but "is there a map $N \colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Z}$, such that $N(x) < x < N(x) + 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$?".